# mongoDB ISO dates to string with moment.js timezone conversion

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, datetime, momentjs

I am very confused about how mongoDB and javascript handle dates/times.

I have many dates given in a specified timezone. I need to store them in ISO format in mongoDB. For example:

Given: `"01.01.2013 15:00"`, this is in New York City's local time.

As my machine is **not** set to NYC's timezone, I created a Date object form this with a given offset of `-04:00`, as NYC is 4 hours behind UTC. So:

`var date = new Date("01-01-2013T15:00-04:00")`. If I open mongo-express to see what it actually stored, it shows `ISODate("2013-01-01T14:00:00.000Z")`.

Then using moment.js to get it in NYC's time:

```
  var test = moment("2013-01-01T14:00:00.000Z");
  var out = test.tz('America/New_York').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
  console.log(out); //January 1st 2013, 9:00:00 am
```

This obviously shows the wrong time, it should show 3:00:00 pm. What am I doing wrong here? I need these times to be the same for **any client** connecting to my application **from any timezone**, they shouldn't be converted. What is the best practice here?

Comment: `var test = moment.utc("2013-01-01T14:00:00.000Z");` Otherwise it's all going to go haywire.

Comment: @NeilLunn Still showing the same output as above though.

Comment: What is the **real** issue here? is it that you have data as strings like `"01.01.2013 15:00"` and you know that represents the time in New York as of creation, and you need it as UTC?

Comment: Yes indeed. Storing it in UTC is what I want to do. However when working with it on the site in the browser, it should display as "01.01.2013 15:00" for any client, as these dates are timezone specific and meaningless for the application if converted to the clients timezone.

Comment: Well that's what is going to just happen with a JavaScript `Date` and you don't need to do anything special, which is kind of the point of why you use UTC. An API therefore should probably be sending the milliseconds since epoch for that purpose. But staying on **one topic** can we just make the question about converting the "local string" to a UTC value `Date`. Yeah?

Comment: @NeilLunn Okay. But they should be stored with an offset of -04:00 correct? This doesn't account for daylight saving time though I think.

Comment: I think the "point" is to let the function work that out based on the date provided. Don't overthink problems other people already solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145619/discussion-between-ffritz-and-neil-lunn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that `"01.01.2013 15:00"` is in `"America/New_York"` timezone, you can parse it using moment-timezone's [`moment.tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) method.

As moment [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) states:

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`.

Here a live example:

```js
var m = moment.tz("01.01.2013 15:00", "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm", "America/New_York");
console.log(m.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looks good to me. I hope the OP is convinced though. I think the OP is getting confused on the issue, and not understanding that the UTC value of this would come out as `"2013-01-01T20:00:00.000Z"` for a string which of course would be correct.

Comment: For me this prints "January 1st 2013, 3:00:00 pm", which is the exact same result if it was treated as in my time zone (which is +10:00).

Comment: @ffritz take a look at the question you asked here and also take at least a few minutes to re-digest the comments already given. Then address your specific concerns ( if any ) with this answer to the nice person who answered you. Which is not me.

Comment: @VincenzoC Thanks a lot and sorry for the late reply, I missed the notification. I thought I can use moment to convert a UTC date object which has no offset (as I don't know the precise offset when storing, considering dailight saving time) to a specific timezones local time. This helped understanding that I first have to convert the strings to moments, then store them.

Comment: @ffritz glad to help, I'm happy you managed to solve your issue.